Implementation of fork() syscall
Even If I copy process and return 2 value for each process , child process doesn't run correctly
I am trying to implement my own OS and fork syscall . So I have implemented fork syscall and receive return value for parent and child process. But child process doesnt work correctly even if stack of child copied correctly.
I call fork like below

int fork() {

    int result;
    asm ( "int $0x80" : "=c" (result) : "a" (syscalNums::FORK));
     char returnValue[20];
       GlobalDescriptorTable::   intToString(result,returnValue);
      printf("FORK HAS FINISHED : ");
    GlobalDescriptorTable :: printDigit(result);
    return result;  // Return the result captured from 'eax'
}
void InitProcess()
{   

    char returnValue[20];
    int pid = fork();
    printf(" TEST : \n");
  
    GlobalDescriptorTable::printDigit(pid);
    printf(" <== \n");
    if(pid==0)
    {
        printf("CHILD PROCESS ID : ");
        printf(returnValue);
        printf("\n");
        _exit();    
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("PARENT PROCESS ID : ");
        printf(returnValue);
        printf("\n");    
     waitpid(-1);
       
    }
}

fork logic like below

case syscalNums::FORK :

            int childId= interruptManager-> getTaskmangar()->ForkTask(cpu);
            char resultValue[20];
            cpu->ecx=5;
            
        break;



common::uint32_t TaskManager::ForkTask(CPUState* cpustate) { 
    if(numTasks >= 256) 
        return 0; 
    //AddTask(tasks[numTasks]);
    tasks[numTasks].state=READY; 
    tasks[numTasks].Ppid=tasks[currentTask].pid; 
    tasks[numTasks].pid=31; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tasks[currentTask].stack); i++) 
    { 
        tasks[numTasks].stack[i]=tasks[currentTask].stack[i]; 
    } 
//Stackten yer alında cpustate'in konumu değişiyor bu nedenle şuanki taskın offsetini hesaplayıp yeni oluşan process'in cpu statenin konumunu ona göre düzenliyorum. Bu işlemi yapmazsam process düzgün şekilde devam etmiyor. 
    common::uint32_t currentTaskOffset=(((common::uint32_t)cpustate - (common::uint32_t) tasks[currentTask].stack)); 
    
    tasks[numTasks].cpustate=(CPUState*)(((common::uint32_t) tasks[numTasks].stack) + currentTaskOffset); //Burada ECX' yeni taskın process id'sini atıyorum. Syscall'a return edebilmek için. 
    // tasks[currentTask].cpustate=(CPUState*)(((common::uint32_t) tasks[numTasks].stack) + currentTaskOffset); //Burada ECX' yeni taskın process id'sini atıyorum. Syscall'a return edebilmek için. 
    tasks[numTasks].cpustate->ecx = 31; 
    
    numTasks++; 
    
    return tasks[numTasks-1].pid; 
}

output of the above code like picture which uploaded.
return value of the fork written in exc register and assign to result variable but there is no return for child process .
what is the error in code or logic. can anybody help me to fix error please ?
